# How to show characters of string in array randomly

Tags: c, dev-c++

I am making my university project in which I want the user to guess the word of that characters randomly shown from an array of strings and I achieve to show characters randomly but the problem is that some characters repeat and some never show.

I have tried to make an array to store an index to that are already shown character then check if it is already in an array or not but I stuck here program not run as I expect.

```
char arrWords[5][10] = { 
                                                    {"Hello"},
                                                    {"world"},
                                                };

// Seed random number generator
srand(time(NULL));

int i, j, k, r, index[5];

// for loop every word in array
for(i=0; i<=5; i++) {

    // for loop every character in i word
    for(j=0; j<=strlen(arrWords[i]); j++) {

        r = random(strlen(arrWords[i]));

        index[j] = r;

        for(k=0; k<=5; k++) {
            printf("%d ", index[k]);
        }           

    }

    printf("\n\n\n");

}

int random(int range){
    int num;
    num = rand() % range;
    return num;
}
```

I want to show "hello" like -> "elolh", "world" -> "dlorw"

Comment: The condition in the for loop  for(i=0; i<=NUMBER_OF_WORDS; i++) { is invalid.

Comment: According to https://linux.die.net/man/3/random you're using the non-standard `random()` function wrong.

Comment: well i have defined it in my program

Comment: Try [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle)

Comment: If you have defined function `random` in your code, then you should show it.

Comment: yeah i have edited my code now i add this function to question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You doesn't check if index is already written in index array. Try below one.

```
int lock;
 // for loop every word in array
for(i=0; i<=5; i++) {
    j=0;
    lock = 0;
    // for loop every character in i word
    while( j<=strlen(arrWords[i])) {

        r = random(strlen(arrWords[i]));
        for(k=0; k < j; k++)
        {
           if(index[k] == r)
              lock++;
        }
        if(lock == 0)
        {
           index[j] = r;
           j++;
        }
        lock = 0;         
    }

    for(k=0; k<=5; k++) {
        printf("%d ", index[k]);
    }  

    printf("\n\n\n");

}
```

Above code is adapted from your original code. However this is kind of inefficient way to do that because while loop waiting until the random function return unavailable index. That's why @David Ranieri's approach is more convenient to achieve what u are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can shuffle the string using random permutation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    char text[] = "Hello world";
    int len = (int)strlen(text);
    int idx, num, tmp;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (idx = 0; idx < len; idx++)
    {
        num = rand() % len--;
        tmp = text[idx];
        text[idx] = text[num];
        text[num] = (char)tmp;
    }
    puts(text);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
rl eowHoldl
```

Comment: `rand() % len` appears unfair.  Consider `len == 3`.  the `for()` generates 27 (3 power 3) randomizations yet there are only 6 permutation (3!).  Those 6 patterns do not occur equally here.

Answer (score 0):

To output a *fair* randomization, decrement the `length` given to `random()`

```
int length = strlen(arrWords[i]);
char rbuf[length + 1];   // VLA
strcpy(rbuf, arrWords[i]);

// for loop every character
while (length > 1) {
  int r = random(length);
  length--;
  // swap
  int t = rbuf[length];
  rbuf[length] = rbuf[r];
  rbuf[r] = t;
}

printf("%s", rbuf);
```